# How to make webview to fit in every android platform?

Tags: android

Is there any suggestions available to make webview fit in all android platforms.

Comment: what? I have no idea what you want to ask. A WebView can't contain an Activity, but an Activity can contain a WebView

Comment: Activity contains views but not reverse.

Comment: An Activity is the frame of your picture. You can't but a frame in your picture. Tell us what you want to achieve, I think you are just using the wrong terms...

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: no.  Slightly longer but still pretty short answer: as Warren and Yugandhar mentioned in their comments, an `Activity` can contain a `WebView`, not vice versa.  You might be misunderstanding what an `Activity` is, since it's not a simple `View` or anything of that nature.  As such, you should probably check out the [`Activity` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 1):

It s not possible to add a activity inside webview in android

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add an activity inside a webview. when we open a webview with a url, it takes the control to that activity. But you can add a webview inside an activity.